# Using OFFSET in a large table by a simple sub-query

Tags: mysql, performance, join, subquery, query-performance

The slow performance for using `OFFSET` in large table has been widely discussed in various blogs, and the most efficient way is to use an `INNER JOIN` as

```
SELECT *
FROM table
INNER JOIN (
SELECT id
FROM table
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100000)
AS results USING(id);
```

but I wonder what is the bennefit of `INNER JOIN` over a simple sub-query as

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id >
(SELECT id
FROM table
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 100000)
LIMIT 10;
```

or more convenient

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN
(SELECT id
FROM table
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100000);
```

In the following example, the `ORDER BY` is assumed the primary key, but obviously other orders or even `WHERE` clause can be added. My question is about comparison in performance of `INNER JOIN` or a simple sub-query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, I would use `LEFT JOIN` instead. Why?

In a `LEFT JOIN` query, you can dictate what keys you want and the order you want to fetch and join, while `INNER JOIN` lets the MySQL Query Optimizer decide which is best. In some cases, the EXPLAIN plan may look horrible but still give good performance.

Instead of

```
SELECT *
FROM table
INNER JOIN (
SELECT id
FROM table
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100000)
AS results USING(id);
```

flip the query to have the keys first

```
SELECT B.*
FROM (SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100000) A
LEFT JOIN table B USING (id);
```

From there, you can control the order by inside in subquery A

```
SELECT B.*
FROM (SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100000 ORDER BY ...) A
LEFT JOIN table B USING (id);
```

or after `USING (id)`

```
SELECT B.*
FROM (SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100000) A
LEFT JOIN table B USING (id)  ORDER BY ...;
```

This way, you should be able to navigate (or paginate) through the keys before locating actual data. To show this using empirical evidence, see my StackOverflow post ([**Fetching a Single Row from Join Table**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023217/491757)) on using `LEFT JOIN` with primary keys.

### Give it a Try !!!